Why would marriage be optional when God has a Son and commanded Adam and Eve to multiply and fill the whole world?
In the beginning when God instituted marriage, He commanded Adam and Eve to multiply and fill the whole world. Both the Old and New Testaments are initiated by marriage contexts, Adam and Eve were married and Jesus who is the savior is born into a marriage headed by Joseph and Mary. These two contexts show how marriage is of value in the scripture.
Genesis 1:28

Then God blessed them, and God said to them, “Be fruitful and multiply; fill the earth and subdue it; have dominion over the fish of the sea, over the birds of the air, and over every living thing that moves on the earth.”

When God said those words, it meant every human being who is capable of marriage should fulfill that obligation to populate the world, but then Paul taught that marriage is optional, and one should be married when overcome with passion. Why would marriage be optional when every man is commanded to leave his parents and be joined to his wife?
Genesis 2:24

Therefore a man shall leave his father and mother and be joined to his wife, and they shall become one flesh. Genesis 2:24


You need to be posting this on Hermeneuticsstackexchange and not on Christianity. They will down vote your questions if it isn't about denominational differences within Christianity

The command to the first male and female persons could be obligatory in order to take the first very necessary step in the propagation of the race. You would need to prove that this command automatically refers to succeeding generations, in order to preclude successive generations from preferring to be celibate.

@NigelJ, 1 Corinthians 7:9, it is better to marry than to burn with passion. A man shall leave his mother and father is also a command

'A man shall leave his father and mother and cleave to his wife' is not a command. It is not imperative. It is not obligatory. It is a statement of fact which does not fully describe the circumstances of its occurrence. 'A man shall walk his dog and have lunch' does not say what day it might be or if it is every day. It just states a fact that it will happen in the future sometime.

@NigelJ, then why does scripture refer to those who resist marriage as scoffers?

I am not familiar with that scripture. Could you quote the reference, please ?

Perhaps it was a command to the human race as a whole, not to individuals. (Also, was it a command or a blessing?)

Up-voted +1. This would have been my own answer. Some may suggest this answer is too short and is only a comment. I would disagree : this question can be answered very simply and straightforwardly. As has been done.

You live up to your name. :)

Paul's advice is based on the reality of the new creation. In Christ, believers have a foretaste of the future existence through the gift of the Spirit of God.

1 For we know that if the earthly tent we live in is destroyed, we
have a building from God, an eternal house in heaven, not built by
human hands  2Meanwhile we groan, longing to be clothed instead with
our heavenly dwelling, 3 because when we are clothed, we will not be
found naked. 4 For while we are in this tent, we groan and are
burdened, because we do not wish to be unclothed but to be clothed
instead with our heavenly dwelling, so that what is mortal may be
swallowed up by life. 5 Now the one who has fashioned us for this very
purpose is God, who has given us the Spirit as a deposit, guaranteeing
what is to come. 6 Therefore we are always confident and know that as
long as we are at home in the body we are away from the Lord. 7 For we
live by faith, not by sight. 8 We are confident, I say, and would
prefer to be away from the body and at home with the Lord. 9 So we
make it our goal to please him, whether we are at home in the body or
away from it. 10 For we must all appear before the judgment seat of
Christ, so that each of us may receive what is due us for the things
done while in the body, whether good or bad. …
14 For Christ’s love compels us, because we are convinced that one
died for all, and therefore all died. 15 And he died for all, that
those who live should no longer live for themselves but for him who
died for them and was raised again. 16 So from now on we regard no one
from a worldly point of view. Though we once regarded Christ in this
way, we do so no longer. 17 Therefore, if anyone is in Christ, the new
creation has come: The old has gone, the new is here! 18 All this is
from God, who reconciled us to himself through Christ and gave us the
ministry of reconciliation: 19 that God was reconciling the world to
himself in Christ, not counting people’s sins against them. And he has
committed to us the message of reconciliation. 20 We are therefore
Christ’s ambassadors, as though God were making his appeal through us.
We implore you on Christ’s behalf: Be reconciled to God. 21 God made
him who had no sin to be sin for us, so that in him we might become
the righteousness of God. (2 Corinthians 5)

He recommended people able to do so to remain single, and live like angels.

29 Jesus replied, “You are in error because you do not know the
Scriptures or the power of God. 30 At the resurrection people will
neither marry nor be given in marriage; they will be like the angels
in heaven. (Matthew 22)


If you want to get technical, the passage in Genesis refers to it as a blessing. That said, the blessing does communicate God’s intentions for mankind as a whole.
I believe this comes into play particularly at the Tower of Babel; God didn't want mankind all coming and living together as one people at that point; he wanted them to go out and conquer the earth. Thus he confused their language to divide them.
That said, there are certain desires built into us that don’t really require a commandment; the desire to reproduce being one of them. We don’t need to be commanded to eat, to breathe, or to love ourselves. Rather these things are assumed as part of our nature (though there are those with psychological issues that may need to learn these things).
The second greatest commandment is to love others as we love ourselves. The commandment assumes that we love ourselves, and by and large that’s a pretty safe assumption. For others, it implies that you should love yourself.
So then, our natural desires are themselves a kind of law that God has built-in to our very bodies, into our flesh (Romans 7). These are good and help guide our survival both individually and as a species. However we must learn to control these impulses and learn to listen to God over and above the law of the flesh.
An ascetic approach to life, where one denies themselves their desires as a way of worshipping God is well founded in scripture. There is the Nazarite vow where one lives their lives with even stricter dietary and other constraints for a period of time. If they become unclean they must start over for the full length of time that they vowed. Or, again, one can fast for a period of time - like when Moses or Christ went 40 days and nights with nothing.
Giving up marriage and fully devoting oneself to God is another way that people can choose to sacrifice of themselves to serve God. Not only is this not a bad thing - but scripture even raises up individuals who do this.
Revelation 14:1-5

Then I looked, and behold, the Lamb was standing on Mount Zion, and with Him 144,000 who had His name and the name of His Father written on their foreheads. 2 And I heard a voice from heaven, like the sound of many waters and like the sound of loud thunder, and the voice which I heard was like the sound of harpists playing on their harps. 3 And they *sang [a]a new song before the throne and before the four living creatures and the elders; and no one was able to learn the song except the 144,000 who had been purchased from the earth. 4 These are the ones who have not defiled themselves with women, for they are celibate. These are the ones who follow the Lamb wherever He goes. These have been purchased from mankind as first fruits to God and to the Lamb. 5 And no lie was found in their mouths; they are blameless.


it is almost impossible to resist your natural desires to server God and this stands in the way of many Christians and that is why they need marriage to remove that platform from being taken advantage of by the devil to drag them down to hell. God created Adam and so do men when they give birth, they create. God is love and marriage is the perfect context for love to demonstrate itself

@SoFewAgainstSoMany it most certainly isn’t impossible in the least. However, that’s not to say it’s easy. Christ had to resist all the temptations common to man whilst facing a cruel death. Among other natural desires - he had to suppress his natural survival instincts and choose to die in order to fulfill God’s will.

I know you are aware that those who resist marriage are struggling with sins that are as a result of resisting marriage. Marriage is also susceptible to temptations like adultery but that is why both partners need to be faithful.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany if you must resist temptations in either case, then marriage isn't the answer to sin.

The answer is found in the study of 'seed'. In the beginning God gives a commandment to spread over the whole earth and multiply.
In the new covenant Messiah changed everything. Seed no longer was about the seed of men, but became about the word.
Luke 8:11 -  The seed is the word of God.
12 Those by the way side are they that hear; then cometh the devil, and taketh away the word out of their hearts, lest they should believe and be saved.
13 They on the rock are they, which, when they hear, receive the word with joy; and these have no root, which for a while believe, and in time of temptation fall away.
14 And that which fell among thorns are they, which, when they have heard, go forth, and are choked with cares and riches and pleasures of this life, and bring no fruit to perfection.
15 But that on the good ground are they, which in an honest and good heart, having heard the word, keep it, and bring forth fruit with patience.
Instead of populating the earth now, the seed of the word is planted by which we now populate the Heavenly Kingdom.
Notice the dichotomy between the same things being said from the OT & NT
Genesis 9:7 - And as for you, be fruitful and multiply; Bring forth abundantly in the earth And multiply in it.”
VS NT
Matthew 28:19 - Go therefore and make disciples of all the nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit
It's the exact same thing. Go out, multiply (make disciples)
One populates the earth (fulfilled) and one populates heaven (in progress)
